# Inner measure of the Irrationals inside $[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis

Here, I am taking Lebesgue measure. There is a notion that a set $E$ is measruable iff $m_*(E) = m^*(E)$. Let $E' = [0,1] \cap \mathbb I$, where $\mathbb I$ denote the set of irrational numbers.

By definition, $m_*(E) = \sup_{F}\{|F| \mid F \subset E, F \text{ compact}\}$. Then, $m_*(E') = \sup_{F}\{m^*(F) \mid F \subset E', F \text{ compact}\}$. Take some compact $F \subset E'$ such that $m^*(E') < m^*(F) + \epsilon$. Then,

1. $F$ must not contain a closed interval.
2. $F$ is nowhere dense in $[0,1]$ since if it is dense in some $O \subset [0,1]$, then compactness $F$ implies that $\mathbb Q \cap F \neq \varnothing$.
3. $F$ has strictly positive measure.

How is this possible?

Comment: I think you mean $$m_{*}(E)=\sup_{F}\{|F|: F\subset E,\, F\text{ compact}\}$$

Comment: @clathratus Yes, Thank you. I fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy to construct such an $F$.

Let $(q_k)_{k=1}^{\infty}$ be an enumeration of the rationals in $[0,1]$, let $0 < c < 1$ be a constant, and let $I_k = (q_k - c2^{-(k+1)}, q_k + c2^{-(k+1)})$.

Let $U = \bigcup I_k$ and $F = [0,1] \setminus U$. Note that $U$ is open, so $F$ is compact. Also note that the measure of $U$ is at most $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} c2^{-k} = c$, so the measure of $F$ is at least $1-c$.

Finally, since $U$ covers $[0,1] \cap \mathbb Q$, it follows that $F$ is contained in $[0,1] \setminus \mathbb Q$.

So, $F$ is compact, has positive measure, and contains only irrationals.

Comment: I think you meant: since measure of $U$ is at most $c$, so the measure of $F$ is at least $1-c$. Other than that, I will take this answer.

Comment: @JamesChung Indeed, thanks. Fixed!

Answer (score 0):

You actually know that there exists by other routes, in fact you know that $|[0,1]\cap \mathbb{Q}|=0$ so it is measurable in the Lebesgue complete measure and it implies that $|[0,1]\cap \mathbb{I}|=1$.

So you know it is possible, the only thing is "how?"; well, we know there exist some ugly sets out there, like the Cantor set, actually you may be able to use a generalized Cantor set.

An other idea is to use the fact that the sets $\{ x \}$ with $x\in [0,1]\cap \mathbb{I}$ are closed and bounded, so compact, and also every finite union of these singletons. It is true that their measure is $0$, but we are talking about their $\sup$, so there is hope.

Comment: I would question your second approach. Every finite union of singletones has measure 0. Taking sup over 0's still gives 0.

Comment: I edited it to say what I really meant, which is that, at least to me, it showed hope; hoping also it could give ideas on how to construct such a set.